# Generate line plot for data with no headers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
Oat   5   9   8   9   6
Gren  6   5   5   2   1
Yera  1   22  9   8   7
Rew   7   8   2   6   9
```

How can I generate a plot for these data in R like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

d <- data.frame(
  'Oat' = c(5, 9,  8, 9, 6), 
  'Gren'  = c(6, 5, 5, 2, 1), 
  'Yera'  = c(1, 22, 9, 8, 7), 
  'Rew' = c(7, 8, 2, 6, 9)
)

d <- melt(d)

plot <- ggplot(data = d, aes(x = rep(1:5, 4), y = value, colour = variable))
plot <- plot + geom_path(group=d$variable, size = 1)
plot <- plot + theme_minimal() + theme(legend.title=element_blank())
plot <- plot + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank())
plot + scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "red", 'darkgoldenrod1', 'darkgreen'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can continue from the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52742120/3962914), by reshaping the dataframe in the similar way and then `group_by` `Type` and create a new column named `row` which is basically `row_number()` in the group and plot it against the `value` column drawing different line for each `Type`.

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(Type = df$V1 , value = unlist(df[-1])) %>%
   arrange(rep(1:(n()/length(df$V1)), each = length(df$V1)), -value)  %>%
   group_by(Type) %>%
   mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
   ggplot() + aes(row, value, col = Type) + geom_line()
```

---

Or a much better and cleaner approach using `gather`

```
df %>%
  gather(Type, value, -V1)  %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(row, value, col = V1) + geom_line()
```

[image]

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Gren", 
  "Oat", "Rew", "Yera"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(5L, 6L, 1L, 
  7L), V3 = c(9L, 5L, 22L, 8L), V4 = c(8L, 5L, 9L, 2L), V5 = c(9L, 
  2L, 8L, 6L), V6 = c(6L, 1L, 7L, 9L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
 "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L))
```